# Are $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\Psi(x)}{\pi(x)}=1$ and $\pi(x)\le\Psi(x)$ true statements?

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, asymptotics, approximation

$$\Psi(x)= \int_2^x \sin(\frac{1}{2\ln(t)})+\sinh(\frac{1}{2\ln(t)})\mathscr{dt}. $$

Does$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\Psi(x)}{\pi(x)}=1? $$

Where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.

Since $$ \Psi(x)\approx \mathscr{li}(x), $$

I believe the conjecture to be true.

Is $$\pi(x)\le\Psi(x)?$$

Comment: Possibly an interesting page for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number

Comment: n the article referenced in the comment  above, it gives a reference for  reent (2o15) ewsukt that \pi(x)\le li(x) for x<10^{19}.

Comment: so $\Psi(x)$ might behave like $\mathscr{li(x)}?$

Comment: can we also use that: $$\pi(x)\approx\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is true that $\Psi(x)\approx \text{Li}(x)$ and we use that $\pi(x)\approx\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ then we can say that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\Psi(x)}{\pi(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\ln(t)}}{x}$$
And now use L'Hopitals rule. Failing this use Squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin x=x+o(x)$ and $\sinh x=x+o(x)$,
$$\Psi (x)=\int^x_2 \frac1{\ln t}dt+\int^x_2 o(\ln t)dt=\operatorname{Li}(x)+o(\operatorname{Li}(x))$$

Hence,
$$\frac{\Psi(x)}{\pi(x)}\sim\frac{\operatorname{Li}(x)}{\pi(x)}\sim 1$$

provided that $\operatorname{Li}(x)/\pi(x)\to1$.